# Setting state using hooks resulting in null value in subsequent function call

Tags: react-native

First I call this where result is an object

```
const _onSaveEvent = async (result) => {
    console.log(result);
    setSignature(result);
    followUp();
};
```

Then I invoke,

```
const handleActualSubmission = async () => {
    console.log(signature);
    const { encoded, pathName } = signature;
    const extension = pathName.split('.').pop();
    const path = `${RNFS.DocumentDirectoryPath}/${uuidv4()}.${extension}`;
    await RNFS.writeFile(path, encoded, 'base64');
    stops.forEach(async (stopForPhotoConf) => {
      await saveDeliveryProof(driverRoute, stopForPhotoConf, path, extension, 'signature');
    });
    close();
  };
```

The resulting error is signature being null on line 1 of `handleActualSubmission` where `const [signature, setSignature] = useState(null);`

I have verifeid that the _onSaveEvent function always returns a truthy value. This issue does not appear every time this sequence of functions runs.

Comment: `setState` is asynchronous! Use `useEffect` if you need triggers when `signature` changes

Comment: @debuchet got it, that makes sense, i know setState but that comes with a callback to act on the successfully set state where useState doesn't. Check my submission for what I think is correct answer. I used useEffect as you suggested

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code should work:

```
useEffect(() => {
    if (signature) {
      processSavedSignature();
    }
  }, [signature]);
```